# Building multidimensional arrays in PHP with foreach

Tags: php, arrays

How would I go about building output like this in PHP:

```
$items[] = array(
    'section_name' => 'Section 1 Name',
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'item_name' => 'Item 1 Name - Section 1'
            // there will be more in here
        ),
        array(
            'item_name' => 'Item 2 Name - Section 1'
            // there will be more in here
        )
    ) 
);
$items[] = array(
    'section_name' => 'Section 2 Name',
    'items' => array(
        array(
            'item_name' => 'Item 1 Name - Section 2'
            // there will be more in here
        ),
        array(
            'item_name' => 'Item 2 Name - Section 2'
            // there will be more in here
        )
    ) 
);
// and so on
```

with this as the input

```
[section] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Section 1 Name
        [item] => Array (
             [0] => Array (
                [name] => Item 1 Name - Section 1
                // there will be more in here
             )
             [1] => Array (
                [name] => Item 2 Name - Section 1
                // there will be more in here                   
             )

        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Section 2 Name
        [item] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [name] => Item 1 Name - Section 2
                // there will be more in here
            )

       )
   )

)
```

There will never be a set number of items in a section and the number of sections will vary too so I need something iterative then a fixed number.

Comment: So what do you want is just to change the keys names ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ? :

```
$sections = [];
for ($sectionIndex = 0; $sectionIndex < 10; ++$sectionIndex) {
  $items = [];
  for ($itemIndex = 0; $itemIndex < 10; ++$itemIndex) {
    $items[] = [
      'item_name' => sprintf('Item %d Name - Section %d', $itemIndex, $sectionIndex);       
    ]; 
  }
  $sections[] = [
    'section_name' => sprintf("Section %d Name", $sectionIndex),
    'items' => $items
  ];
}
```

Replace [] by array, since I don't know which PHP version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Pass this your input array $section

```
 $items=array();
 $item=array();
 foreach ($section as $row) { 
    $tmp=array();
   $tmp['section_name']=$row['name'];
   foreach($row['item'] as $key){
          $item[]['item_name']=$key['name'];
   }
   $tmp['items']=$item;
   $items[]=$tmp;
 }

 print_r($items);
```

Comment: This seems to mostly work although it compounds so the second Items array includes all the items from the first as well as the ones from the second

Answer (score 0):

Solved with a slightly modified version of the answer from @NoDataFound

```
    $sections = [];
    $s = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['section'] as $section) {
        $s++;
        $items = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($section['item'] as $item) {
            $i++;
            $items[] = [
                'item_name' => sprintf('Item %d Name - Section %d', $i, $s)   
            ]; 
        }
        $sections[] = [
            'section_name' => sprintf("Section %d Name", $s),
            'items' => $items
        ];
    }
```